# Why is GRPC Unavailable from a different computer?

Tags: grpc, gatling

I have been adding GPRC to a micro service I am working on. So far everything works okay, and I have a simple gatling test to verify things work correctly.

However, things only seem to work when I run gatling on the same system as my micro service. When I run the same test on a different system, I always get back an `UNAVAILABLE` response.

The first part of the test makes an HTTP request (port 8080), and that always succeeds, but the second part of the test makes a GRPC request (port 8081); which always succeeds on the same system, but always fails when the client is on a different system on the network.

I have tried opening up firewalls and such on Windows where the micro service is running, but no luck.

My micro service is running on Windows, and my other system is OS X.

Does anyone have any troubleshooting tips wrt GRPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programmer error: I was not using the correct test host name on the GRPC port. Test works now, except that it cannot handle the same load as the HTTP test. So, something new to investigate.